# Any idea why I am getting this HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH error?

Tags: php, debugging

I uploaded my website to my webhost. It uses PHP, MySQL. The webhost has both of those. I am getting this error: `An error occurred in script '/usr/local/lib/php/foot.php' on line 3: Undefined index:  HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH`.

The weird thing is that as far as I can see that directory does not exist on my website. Any ideas what it may be?

Comment: This is not a "directory on your website", but a directory on the system, where it runs. You should show us some code out of the file `foot.php`.

Comment: @KingCrunch I do not have access to foot.php is the thing.

Answer (score 2):

It's PHP complaining that you're attemping to access an array with a key that doesn't exist. Given the name of the key, probably you've got `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']`.